# Followup: Generalist Badge. Why not gold?

Tags: discussion, badges

@JeffAtwood said "But it is a very hard badge to get; much larger sites only have ~20 users with the badge."

So why isn't this a gold badge?

**Edit:** Nevermind.  In a case of "I should've checked SO-meta first..." [Here's the discussion from stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50925/the-generalist-badge-should-be-gold)